# undefined reference to c++ static library from c code when compiling using g++

Tags: c++, c, c++11, gcc

I want to try interfacing C++ from C using the following setup:

**interface.h**:

```
#ifndef MY_TEST_INTERFACE_H
#define MY_TEST_INTERFACE_H

void *CreateDictionary();
void DictionaryAdd(void *self, const char *key, const char *value);
const char *DictionaryGetItem(void *self, const char *key);
void ReleaseDictionary(void **self);

#endif /* MY_TEST_INTERFACE_H */
```

**lib.cpp**

```
#include <unordered_map>

extern "C" void *CreateDictionary() 
{
    std::unordered_map<const char *, const char *> *dict = new std::unordered_map<const char *, const char *>;

    return reinterpret_cast<void *>(dict);
}    

extern "C" void DictionaryAdd(void *self, const char *key, const char *value)
{
    std::unordered_map<const char *, const char *> *dict = reinterpret_cast<std::unordered_map<const char *, const char *> *>(self);
    (*dict)[key] = value;
}

extern "C" const char *DictionaryGetItem(void *self, const char *key)
{
    std::unordered_map<const char *, const char *> *dict = reinterpret_cast<std::unordered_map<const char *, const char *> *>(self);
    return (*dict)[key];
}

extern "C" void ReleaseDictionary(void **self)
{
    std::unordered_map<const char *, const char *> **dict = reinterpret_cast<std::unordered_map<const char *, const char *> **>(self);
    delete (*dict);
    *self = 0;
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include "interface.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    void *dict = CreateDictionary();
    DictionaryAdd(dict, "color", "Green");
    const char *str = DictionaryGetItem(dict, (const char *)"color");
    puts(str);
    ReleaseDictionary(&dict);

    return 0;
}
```

**What I did**

I compiled lib.cpp using

`g++ lib.cpp -o lib.obj -std=c++11 -std=gnu++11-c`

Then built the static libary using

`ar crf lib.a lib.obj`

I am now trying to link `lib.a` with `main.c` using

`g++ main.c lib.a -o main -std=c++11 -std=gnu++11`

However I am getting the error:

```
C:\Users\Dmitry\AppData\Local\Temp\ccWnD011.o:main.c:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `CreateDictionary()'
C:\Users\Dmitry\AppData\Local\Temp\ccWnD011.o:main.c:(.text+0x2f): undefined reference to `DictionaryAdd(void*, char const*, char const*)'
C:\Users\Dmitry\AppData\Local\Temp\ccWnD011.o:main.c:(.text+0x43): undefined reference to `DictionaryGetItem(void*, char const*)'
C:\Users\Dmitry\AppData\Local\Temp\ccWnD011.o:main.c:(.text+0x5f): undefined reference to `ReleaseDictionary(void**)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am building this on MINGW g++ 5.3.0.

I am curious why my C program can't find the references to the functions I marked under extern C, and compiled using g++ to ensure the c++ runtime is linked.

Comment: Compile your c progr by gcc

Comment: Well I'll be, that actually worked... O.o

Comment: Your definitions in `lib.cpp` are all `extern "C"`, but your declarations in the header aren't. And you're building the program that includes the header with a C++ compiler.

Comment: Anyway, in your header, you should wrap it in #ifdef __cplusplus extern "C" {

Comment: I am not sure how to do that, and why it would work. Can you explain? I mean I tried http://hastebin.com/tejezerawe.cs but it didn't fix it. I needed to compile the c program by gcc before linking it with g++(because it complained about lacking references to new, delete)

Comment: Why are you specifying a file name for your library object with -o instead of simply using -c ?

Comment: @technosaurus because otherwise it gives it a default name if I remember correctly.